# Generate Box Plots side-by-side to compare two Dataframes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

### Problem

I have two data frames with the *same set of attributes* and a different amount of entities in them.

Now I want to compare selected attributes by generating boxplots side-by-side. I have three questions and want to share what I have tried so far.

#### Seaborn

```py
import seaborn as sns

data_a = sns.load_dataset("tips")
data_b = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.boxplot(data=[data_a["tip"], data_b["tip"]])
```

[image: This is the result. But labels are still missing.]

**Question 1**
How can I set labels to these two boxplots?

#### Matplotlib

I tried matplotlib as well, but I am not sure how to set the positions of the two boxplots, they always overlap:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data_a = sns.load_dataset("tips")
data_b = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
first_data = ax.boxplot(data_a["tip"])
second_data = ax.boxplot(data_b["tip"])
```

[image: Now, both my plots overlap.]

My plots overlap and I do not understand how to set the plots side-by-side. [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612687/python-matplotlib-box-plot-two-data-sets-side-by-side) mention the `positions` parameter.

So my other questions are:

**Question 2**

How can I prevent two `matplotlib` boxplots from overlapping for example by using the parameter `positions`?

**Question 3**

Also with `matplotlib`: How do I set labels to the axes and plots? (y = "Tip", x = "Data Set", data_a = "First Data Set", data_b = "Second Data Set")

Thank you.

Comment: Q1:`g = sns.boxplot(data=[data_a["tip"], data_b["tip"]]);g.set_ylabel('Tip')`Q2:`first_data=ax.boxplot([data_a["tip"], data_b["tip"]])`Q3:`ax.set_ylabel('Tips');ax.set_xticks([1,2]);ax.set_xticklabels(["First Data Set","Second Data Set"])`

Comment: Thanks, the same labeling strategy works for Q1. `g.set_xticks([0,1]);
g.set_xticklabels(["First Data Set","Second Data Set"])`. What are "ticks"?

Comment: It's an engraved scale.